how to make sub-shell env variable available in the main shell python console?
I open a python console and run
>>> import os
>>> os.system("export aaa=123")
>>> os.environ["aaa"]

I see a key error. Why is that?
How can I preserve the env variables across the entire process?
note that this is not the right answer:
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['abc'] = '123'
>>> os.system('echo $abc')
123

the purpose of this question is to demonstrate a situation that a sub-shell is generating an env variable and one might want to share it with the parent shell

It's not clear exactly what you want to achieve. Should your child process modify the environment of its parent process, or of all of its parent processes, or of all processes running in your computer? This is fortunately not how Linux is designed. If you want two processes to share a piece of information, consider using shared memory instead.

os.system starts a new process; it does not magically execute shell code in the original Python process.

As others say, a subshell cannot affect the environment of the supershell. But not all is lost, if the supershell is allowed to cooperate.
The way most programs that need to change the supershell's environment work is that they print the variable definitions and expect them to be executed in the supershell. For a famous example, ssh-agent is supposed to be used like this:
$ eval `ssh-agent`

ssh-agent outputs something like
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXkZD1hM/agent.200830; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=200831; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 200831;

and when you apply the shell builtin eval to it, the variables get defined in the current shell. You can apply something similar for yourself:
import os
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(
    "echo aaa=123; echo bbb=456",
    shell=True, encoding='utf-8',
)
vars = { k: v for k, v in [row.split('=', 1) for row in output.splitlines()] }
os.environ.update(vars)

print(os.environ["aaa"])
# => 123
print(os.environ["bbb"])
# => 456

Note that this is tailored to the scenario you describe: passing variables from a subshell to os.environ of the invoking Python program. There are other ways to communicate, as VonWooDSoN rightfully points out, both between two Python processes (e.g. multiprocessing), as well as between heterogeneous processes (e.g. Redis).

Set the environment variable in the Python process
os.environ['aaa'] = "123"
Now, or later in the process you can access it as a normal environment variable
print(os.environ['aaa'])

os.system() creates a shell subprocess (bash, cmd.exe, ...). Subprocesses do not have access to their parent environment (it's copied). They can not modify it. You could change your current environment (not a child one) and have the subprocesses inherit it:
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['abc'] = '123'
>>> os.system('echo $abc')
123


It's not a subshell, as you aren't in a shell to begin with.

@chepner A "subshell" in the Python world refers to a new (child) shell process that is created to execute commands. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system "Execute the command (a string) in a subshell."

That's lazy wording in the Python documentation.

@chepner ok, changed. The accepted answer starts with "in the parent shell." btw...
